# How to import data from sql database to a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sql

I would need to import 2 columns of data from a SQL database into a SharePoint list? Is there a way to easily import data from a sql database to a SharePoint list?

Answer (score 2):

**BCS:** Business connectivity Service allows us to connect external data and work with it from SharePoint.Just we need to create an external content type.

[Getting started with Business Connectivity Services (BCS) in SharePoint 2010](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-getting-started-with-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010)

**PS:** Steps are also same for SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Security;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;  
  
namespace SqlDataConnection  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            string userName = "<provide your username to connect to the SharePoint site>";  
            string password = "<provide your password>";   
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();  
            foreach (char c in password)  
            {  
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);  
            }  
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Practice/"))  
            {  
                // SharePoint Online Credentials    
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);  
                Web web = clientContext.Web;      
                clientContext.Load(web);     
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  
  
                List productList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Products");  
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
                dt = GetDatafromSQL();  
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.  
                {  
                    ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();  
                    ListItem newItem = productList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);  
                    newItem["ProductID"] = dr["ProductID"];  
                    newItem["Name"] = dr["Name"];  
                    newItem["ProductNumber"] = dr["ProductNumber"];  
                    newItem.Update();  
                    clientContext.Load(newItem);  
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  
  
                }  
                clientContext.Load(productList);  
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  
  
            }  
        }  
  
        private static DataTable GetDatafromSQL()  
        {  
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();  
            string connString = @"Server=<provide server url>;Database=<Database Name>;Integrated Security=True";  
            string query = "SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, p.ProductNumber from Production.Product p where p.ProductID<500;";  
  
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);  
            connection.Open();  
  
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
            da.Fill(dataTable);  
            connection.Close();  
            da.Dispose();  
  
            return dataTable;  
        }  
    }  
}
```